# Jquery $.AjaxError detect if there is a custom error handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I want to set a default handler for ajax error:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
    //my custom handler;
});
```

However I don't want to run my handler if in the jqXHR there is a custom error function already set.

for example:

in case of error this does not throw the default error handler (there is custom handler):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'test',
   error: function(){}
});
```

in case of error this throws the default error handler:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'test'
});
```

is it possibile? I tried to inspect the jqXHR.error object inside the ajaxError but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found, I have to set ajaxSetup instead of ajaxError

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   error:function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
      // mycustom handler
   }
});
```